# Can listener get parameters

Tags: java, shell, text, swt

I created listeners to texts- when clicked open a shell.
I also created modify listeners - when clicked should update a graph according to parameters.

Then in a loop I change the text of the Texts, is it possible to send somehow the value of the Text as parameter to the listener?

Thank you?

Comment: add a code snippet, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understand your problem correctly, but have you tried the [Widget#setData method](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/ntopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Widget.html#setData%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29)?
Thus you can store your parameters for each text widget and retrieve the data in your listener (the widget can be obtained from your listener's event).

Code to set your data:

```
text.setData("a_parameter_key", "parameter_value");
```

Code in your Listener (if org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener)

```
void handleEvent (Event event) {
    ...
    String myParameter = (String)event.widget.getData("a_parameter_key");
    ...
}
```